# Using Docker for create react app without using Nodejs to serve the file

Tags: reactjs, docker

Without using NodeJs to serve the static file, I am trying to build Docker image for create react app with the below folder structure

```
sampleapp -
          client
            src
            ...
          DockerFile
```

So client is build by **create-react-app client**, the application is just consuming services and rendering it.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.15.1-alpine
COPY . /var/panda/client
WORKDIR /var/panda/client
RUN  npm install --no-cache && npm run build
EXPOSE 4000 
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

How can I start the Docker container in local and prod, and is the above Docker script is fine for running the application in production build?

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing. Do you mean you don't want to use node.js in the container? Or that you want to use node.js in the container instead of on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to run an image, you simply do `docker build -t client .`, and then `docker run client`. Your `Dockerfile` is not fine for a prod environment because it runs as `root`. You should add the following lines just before the last line.

```
RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've [run `npm run build`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment) you will have a set of static files you can serve.  Anything that serves static files will work fine.  One typical setup is to use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to first build the application, then serve it out of an Nginx image:

```sh
FROM node:10.15.1-alpine AS build
COPY . /var/panda/client
WORKDIR /var/panda/client
RUN  npm install --no-cache && npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17
COPY --from=build /var/panda/client/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

For day-to-day development, just use the ordinary CRA tools like `npm run start` directly on your desktop system.  You'll get features like live reloading, and you won't have to mess with Docker volumes or permissions.  Since the application ultimately runs in the browser it can't participate in things like Docker networking; except for pre-deployment testing there's not really any advantage to running it in Docker.